How can Weber's approach be compatible with evolutionism?
Weber's epistemology is synthesized in one paragraph in Economy and Society (1921):

Sociology (in the sense in which this-highly ambiguous word is used here) is a science concerning itself with the interpretive understanding of social action and thereby with a causal explanation of its course and consequences. We shall speak of "action" insofar as the acting individual attaches a subjective meaning to his behavior-be it overt or covert,
omission or acquiescence. Action is "social"insofar as its subjective mean- ing takes account of the behavior of others and is thereby oriented in its course.s

The sociologist Raymond Boudon classifies Weber as an evolutionist. He develops this in a long section "An evolutionist conception" in (Boudon 2001), so here just one short quote:

Weber deserves to be classed as an evolutionist insofar as the identification and explanation of historical irreversibilities is an essential subject for him.

In my impression, Weber was an antipositivist, while evolutionism is a positivist approach. Indeed, for Weber, sociology, economy and history were "sciences of culture", in opposition to "sciences of nature", and therefore they could not borrow the methods of the "sciences of nature".
So how can Weber's approach be comptabible with evolutionism?
References:
Weber, M. (1921). Economy and society. A. A. Editor & B. B. Editor (Eds.). University of California Press.
Boudon, R. (2001). La rationalité du religieux selon Max Weber. L'Année sociologique, 51(1), 9-50.

Boudon's use of the term "evolution" seems quite vague and not necessarily linked with Darwinian and modern evolutionism.

Maybe the key-word is "historical irreversibility".

Boudon just limits examples of "evolutionists" to Comte, Spencer and Mill. But Peirce, Bergson, Spengler, Teilhard de Chardin and Foucault were also evolutionists and none of them can be suspected of positivism. In fairness, Boudon does say that Weber's "view of evolution is particularly cautious and nuanced. Thus, it is more acceptable than the “classic” versions" of positivists that "all appear much more mechanical and “fatalistic” than his". And he applies "evolution" to "history of ideas", which is standard in anti-positivist historicism.

@Conifold How can we be "evolutionist" and "antipositivist"? I mean, positivism is IMU a strong commitment to science, in particular natural sciences, and "evolutionism" is rooted in natural sciences (biology).

There is no relation in either direction. Strong commitment to science is shared by physicalism and all forms of scientific realism and anti-realism. Evolutionism is a commitment to evolving nature, culture and/or being generally, which may or may not dovetail with modern science (Bergson's and Chardin's did not at all). As applied to "history of ideas", it goes back to Hegel, and historicist interpretations are often considered "anti-science" because they undermine objectivity of scientific notions and portray them as shifting and culturally/socially dependent.

@Conifold Ok, but Darwinian evolutionism = positivism + evolutionism, right? Aron pointed that Weber was indeed influenced by darwinian evolutionism: "Or, le fait est que Max Weber, qui admettait évidemment cette hétérogénéité, a plutôt atténué et comme brouillé la distinction. Il a été, me semble-t-il, impressionné et quelque peu influencé par la vision darwinienne de la réalité sociale." (Aron, 1967,
Les Étapes de la pensée sociologique)

Darwinian evolution is not specific to positivism either. I already mentioned scientific realism/anti-realism. Almost all of analytic philosophy and other forms of naturalism accept it. But not social Darwinism that Aron is talking about, which Spencer promoted but already 20th century positivists eschewed. Weber and Kidd were influenced by its early 19th century forms. Nazi ideologues later picked it up cheerfully, and they were no positivists.

@Conifold (1) It can be argued that Weber was indeed very much influenced by Darwinian evolutionism "Weber's (1958, pp. 55, 72; 1967, p. 320) explicit use in the relevant texts of concepts which are obviously derived from Darwinian theory: 'selection', 'adaptation', 'economic survival of the fittest', 'economic struggle for existence'."

(2) while keeping distant from social darwinism "while using a concept sociocultural selection analogous to the Darwinian concept of natural selection, Weber was careful to avoid -- and wanted to make sure his readers avoided -- the obvious flaw in the social Darwinian paradigm (and my implication in much of contemporary sociobiology)." https://www.jstor.org/stable/42852826?read-now=1&seq=3#page_scan_tab_contents

Just as Conifold says, you're just being stuck on the word "evolutionist" because you think it can refer to nothing else than biological evolution. It would be understandable if Boudon did not clarify what he means by this word right in your own quote: "insofar as the identification and explanation of historical irreversibilities". It is to say: societies change with time and Weber thinks some of those those changes are irreversible, and sets to explain why they are. "Change with time" in common parlance is called "evolution", and that's why Boudin uses this word.

I’m voting to close this question because this question comes from a misunderstanding of the source material

Humans just stubbornly refuse to comply with dictionary definitions in their approaches to things! Exasperating.
